# problems with ChartJS refresh in angular component

Tags: angular-material, chart.js

In my project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/planificador?file=src/app/planificador/components/subcontrataciones/subcontrataciones.component.ts

I have in a mat-expansion-panel a component with a ChartJS canvas but the problem I have is that once configured, the data is assigned to the chart when I open the extension panel, these are not shown until I stretch the screen.

That is to say, from the start I see this

[image: empty]

and after stretching and shrinking the screen the data appears

[image: data]

In grafica.component.ts I have this

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.mostrarGraficoMezclado();
```

}

```
 mostrarGraficoMezclado() {
this.canvas = this.mychart.nativeElement;
this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

var options = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        barPercentage: 0.5,
        barThickness: 6,
        maxBarThickness: 8,
        minBarLength: 2,
        gridLines: {
          offsetGridLines: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

var mixedChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Contratado Previsto",
        data: this.contratoPrevistoAcumulado,
        borderColor: "blue",
        type: "line"
      },
      {
        label: "Gastado Realizado",
        data: this.gastadoRealizadoAculumado,
        borderColor: "green",
        type: "line"
      },
      {
        label: "Certificado Realizado",
        data: this.certificadoRealizadoAculumado,
        borderColor: "red",
        type: "line"
      },
      {
        label: "Gasto Previsto Total",
        data: this.gastadoPrevisto,
        backgroundColor: "orange"
      },
      {
        label: "Certificado Previsto",
        data: this.certificadoPrevisto,
        backgroundColor: "maroon"
      },
      {
        label: "Historico de Previsiones",
        data: this.historicoPrevisionesN,
        backgroundColor: "black"

      }
    ],
    labels: this.etiquetasEjeX
  },
  options: options
});
```

}

Any idea, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved if you don't invoke `mostrarGraficoMezclado()` inside `ngAfterViewInit()` but rather at the end of `getDatosGlobalesGrafica()`, just after `getDatosGrafica()`.

This makes sure, the chart gets created only once its data is available.

```
getDatosGlobalesGrafica(proyectoId: string, acumular: boolean) {
  ...
  zip(...)
     .pipe(...)
     .subscribe(
        ...
        this.getDatosGrafica();
        this.mostrarGraficoMezclado();
     );
  );  
}
```